# How to separate between data selecting from multiple tables?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to search in 16 different tables, but I don't wanna repeat the "select from DB" 16 times; I think that's not really help in performance!!!

I am using:

```
query="SELECT * FROM table1, table2,..., table16 WHERE id=?";
```

Is it correct ??
my problem is how to separate between data of tables ??

also maybe I can get from one table two  or more results for one "id"; So I want to know which data is from which table !!
.
Best regards,

Comment: You should post your table structures with sample data and expected results.  As is, it's difficult to answer or understand.  Your query is producing a `cartesian product` of the results and assumes only a single `id` field exists in one of those tables, not more than one (which wouldn't make much sense)...

Comment: Be careful with your attempted query as it is a cross join between all 16 tables, returning the Cartesian product of each table set. So, just without a `WHERE` clause, total records is the product of each table's count of records (which may reach into millions): t1 X t2 X t3...

Comment: thanks Parfait, 

Mr sgeddes, this 16 tables are related with a client by an "id" as foreign key; So I want to make a research in this 16 tables to find all the information relate with that client....

Like i say maybe the client have more than one result in a table, 
............
For example the client is a costumer and we have a table called commands , so The costumer maybe he have more than one command in the commands table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not work, because you are trying to join those multiple tables, whereas what you want to do is search (filter) those 16 tables.

You could use a `union all` to do this in a single query:

```
select xxx, 'table1' as source_table
    from table1
where id = ?
union all
select xxx, 'table2' as source_table
    from table2
where id = ?
```

and so on. The second derived field `source_table` can be used to determine which table returned which result.

Comment: I don't understand it to that far, I mean what's those xxx and I do that for the 16 tables or what!!!..............and how they will present in resultset ??

Comment: @Joseph Your original question was about searching for an id in 16 different tables, but from your other comments, it looks like you have phrased it incorrectly. Do you have a **main** table and 15 **child** tables? And do you want to find a record in the main table and all the related information from the child tables?

Comment: Look I will detail it:
I have a table of client contain the client id, name and last name, job ..etc...
also I have 16 tables of the grants of client each table contain a different data(different grant) relate with the client by a foreign key of "id".......So when I search for client I search also for all the grants that benefited them, and maybe client can benefit from the same grant more than once........that means we can find more than one row in the same table relate with the same client, the problem is how I can get all the information relate with that client ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to list all fields using aliases for fields with same name, and prefix with table names.

For example :

```
query = "SELECT table1.id as id_1, table2.id as id_2, ... WHERE id_1 = 23"
```

Probably a very long query to write, but you have solution to generate and paste it : You can do this for example with [FlySpeed SqlQuery](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-querytool.html) (free for personal use)

FlySpeed SqlQuery will generate all aliases for you, and automatically prefix with table names.

Answer (score 0):

A little clarification would help.  If all 16 tables have the same fields and you want them in a continuous list, you can use UNION as suggested above.  On the other hand, if there are only a few fields that match and you want to compare the values for each table side-by-side, you'll want to use joins and provide aliases with the table names, as also suggested above.

However, looking at the snippet of code you've provided, I'm going to guess that you're either building some kind of stored procedure or else implementing SQL in some other language.  If that's the case, how about loading your table names into an array and using a for loop to build the query, such as the following psuedo-code:

```
tableList = ["table1", "table2"...]
fieldnames = ["field1", "field2"...]

query = "SELECT "

for i = 0 to count(tableList):
    for j = 0 to count(fieldnames):
         query = query + tablelist[i] + "." + fieldnames[j] + ", "
    j++
i++

query = query + "FROM " 

for i = 0 to count(tableList):
    query = query + tableList[i] + ", "
i++

query = query + "WHERE " ...
```

And so forth.  Much of this depends on what exactly you're looking to do, how often you're looking to do it, and how often the variables (like which tables or fields you're using) are going to change.

Comment: My real problem is not to how to write query, but how to get data from resultset and how to know which data from which table !!!..thanks